# flutter, How to solve the problem of increasing memory every time I change the size of the app?

Tags: windows, flutter, memory, memory-leaks, resize

people.

I have an issue as below.
Could anybody explain for me how I can handle/solve the below issue?

Please let me know how ~.

- Problem : Memory continues to increase whenever app size is changed with Mouse.
- Env : Flutter, Windows10-64bit, VSCode, run Windows App
- Code : Basic code created when creating a New Project in VSCode

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCCDY.png)

I searched for memory leaks and garbage collection but couldn't find anything about this problem.
I want to solve the problem of increasing memory.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please write out the memory increase as text instead of an image for accessibility.

Comment: If you continue resizing, the memory continues to increase at about 400M and then dies over 8G.